# Dismissing previously presented modal view controller before currently visible one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, hierarchy, presentviewcontroller

I have 2 `UIViewController's` presented with `[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];`, I want to dismiss the first one of them, without animation (It's not visible to the user anyway) and when the second one (currently visible) will be dismissed, the user will see the parent view controller who present them both.

```
- Parent
  - First -> Dismiss first without animation
    - Second -> Dismiss second with animation
```

How can I do that?

Comment: you want to dismiss first view controller but want to dismiss second later on?

Comment: @Usama Yeah.. that's what I want to do.

Comment: If, at the moment you want to dismiss the second, you dismiss the first viewController instead, then the second will be dismissed with animation, and the parent will be visible (without showing the first again). That seems to be exactly the UI behaviour you want. Why do you want to dismiss the first earlier than the second?

Comment: Why? I want the user to dismiss the second one and than return to the parent instead to the first. I also don't want him to see the first one, like he has already removed when he moved to the second.

Answer (score 0):

With your current view controller hierarchy if first view controller will be dismissed it will dismiss second view controller automatically. If you don't want that behaviour than make parent present second view controller. You can do that from first view controller by using `[self.presentingViewController presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil]`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this?

You should do it like this for cleaner view hierarchy and better user experience:

**Present first view controller :**

```
[self presentViewController:viewController1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Dismiss first & present second view controller :**

```
__weak MyViewController *aBlockSelf = self;

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [aBlockSelf presentViewController:viewController2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Comment: This technically works but leads to a poor transition when dismissing and presenting the second view controller. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827981/dismiss-and-present-modal-view-controller-with-one-animation/43825369#43825369 for a way to animate the transition better.